# MySQL : query to find only lines in a table without similar lines in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, A and B, with an "ID" column and I want only ID from table A which don't exist in table B.
I found a command which seems to be great for that, EXIST / MINUS, but it doesn't seem to work in my case... SQL syntax error #1064
Would you know a query to do this please ?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results and your current query.

Comment: You can use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`. In Standard SQL you can also use `EXCEPT` (which is called `MINUS` in Oracle), but this is not available in MySQL.

Comment: Next time, please show your query, so we can tell you what's causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, the query sounds like:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where b.id = a.id);
```